# Randomize selection from snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to select 1,000 random rows from a database of 97 million rows. I am using the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE"
ORDER BY                                         
   RAND()                                      LIMIT 1000
```

I tried this code and got an error stating "SQL compilation error: Unknown function RAND." Is there a better way to do this in Snowflake? I am worried that this code only works in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Using  [SAMPLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/sample.html) clause:

> **Returns a subset of rows sampled randomly from the specified table.** The following sampling methods are supported:
>
> - Sample a fraction of a table, with a specified probability for including a given row. The number of rows returned depends on the size of the table and the requested probability. A seed can be specified to make the sampling deterministic.
> - **Sample a fixed, specified number of rows. The exact number of specified rows is returned unless the table contains fewer rows.**

```
SELECT *
FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE"
SAMPLE (1000 ROWS);
```

Comment: Note that only up to 1M rows is supported. Otherwise you need to use the RANDOM() approach below.

Answer (score 2):

In Snowflake the function is [RANDOM()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/random.html), not RAND().

So your original query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE"
ORDER BY
   RANDOM()
LIMIT 1000
```

But as Lukasz mentioned, SAMPLE() function is the native way to do it in Snowflake.